# How do I get the current year and prior year of a numeric column using a date column?

Tags: sql-server

How do I get the current year and prior year of a numeric column using a date column?

Columns available are 
Premium Column that has a calculated/numeric value. Example would be 115.20, 325,126.29.
Date column. Example would be 03/09/2016, 12/10/2015

```
Date column   Premium Column
03/09/2016    115.20
12/10/2015    325,126.29
```

I need to create 2 new columns, Current Date Premium and Prior Date premium.

The results I need to get for Current Date premium is 115.20
and for prior column is 325,126.29

```
Current Date premium   Prior Date premium
115.20                 325,126.29
```

How do I apply the date part function for this two new columns if the date part does not allow another expression (numeric column like Premium Column) to get the current year?

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL server 2008 and above you can try like below. You can also try replacing the inner query part with a CTE to refactor.

**Logic:**
Inner query provides a ranking on the table rows based on dates and then we do a self join based on a (current table's rank)=(prior table's rank)-1

```
SELECT 
 t1.[Premium Column] as [Current Date Premium],
 t2.[Premium Column] as [Prior Date Premium]
FROM 
 (
  SELECT 
   *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date column] ASC) AS Ranking 
   FROM Tbl 
  )t1 
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
   *, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date column] ASC) AS Ranking 
  FROM Tbl 
)t2
 ON t1.Ranking=t2.Ranking-1
```

Comment: Can't we put the Premium and use it as an expression inside a date function? Or maybe use a case function?

Comment: Please post sample code of what you just wrote. We can improve on that,